# Rails and jQuery not working sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails 4 and jQuery, but I seem to have a minor conflict of sorts with two functions.

The first function is a scroll to top function.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).offset().top > 600) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(500);
    }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});
```

The other is a nested attributes (RailsCast Tutorial) function.

```
$(function() {
      $("form").on("click", ".remove_fields", function(event) {
        $(this).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
        $(this).closest("fieldset").hide();
        return event.preventDefault();
      });
      return $("form").on("click", ".add_fields", function(event) {
        var regexp, time;
        regexp = void 0;
        time = void 0;
        time = new Date().getTime();
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data("id"), "g");
        $(this).before($(this).data("fields").replace(regexp, time));
        return event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Now one works, while the other doesn't and i'm not sure what the issues is. If I cut and re-paste the nested attributes jQuery it works, but if I click the scroll to it doesn't work.

I'm new to jQuery, so i'm not sure if there would be a conflict of sorts.

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps to this gem https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks but instead of moving down //= require turbolinks just remove it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem.

Add `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to your Gemfile then run `bundle install`.

Then modify your `application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install `jquery-turbolinks` gem. And then, don't forget to move your included Javascript files from end of body of your `application.html.erb` to its `<head>`.

If you have put the application javascript link in the footer for speed optimization reasons, you will need to move it into the tag so that it loads before the content in the tag. This solution worked for me.